# Minimal graphing library

Tags: java, directed-acyclic-graphs

What "graphing" algorithm library do people recommend for java that can do the following:

1. Take custom objects as nodes (assume all the same object type)
2. Allow specification of connections between these nodes
3. Provide standard algorithms on these nodes (cycle detection, shortest path...)
4. Allow for custom visitors on the nodes + connections (visitor pattern)

Not be overly complex (if possible).
Have some decent level of javadoc (+ a maven package would be nice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this useful, I have used it in past

http://www.jgrapht.org

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a visualization package, or just the algorithms? In the past I've used JUNG, and found it to be very accessible for this sort of work, although it's primarily focused on visualization rather than analysis.

http://jung.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[HypergraphDB](http://www.hypergraphdb.org) is full-featured and mature, although you may find it too heavyweight for simple applications.